# PackageManager: Not granting permission - Android M

Tags: android, apk, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-install-apk, android-app-indexing

I am using an app for some benchmarking purpose

When I install the app I'm getting these logs from packagemanager. The
android version is Marshmallow and I know that the app targetSdkVersion is 22 (so I expect this to work with M)

```
09-07 02:24:05.407  1174  1204 W PackageManager: Not granting permission android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE to package com.antutu.ABenchMark because it was previously installed without
09-07 02:24:05.407  1174  1204 W PackageManager: Not granting permission android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to package com.antutu.ABenchMark because it was previously installed without
09-07 02:24:05.407  1174  1204 W PackageManager: Not granting permission android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to package com.antutu.ABenchMark because it was previously installed without
```

I am installing the app from a script once the boot completes

```
pm install -r /system/priv-app/Benchmarking/app/app-debug.apk > /dev/kmsg
pm grant com.antutu.ABenchMark android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
pm grant com.antutu.ABenchMark android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
pm grant com.antutu.ABenchMark android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
am start -n com.antutu.ABenchMark/com.antutu.ABenchMark.ABenchMarkStart -e 74Sd42l35nH e57b6eb9906e27062fc7fcfcc820b957a5c33b649 > /dev/kmsg
```

Also I am using a h/w emulator instead of development board so its like trying a fresh OS each time and install app

Answer (score 0):

When you uninstall it before you install it again your problem will probably be fixed

```
 pm uninstall -r /system/priv-app/Benchmarking/app/app-debug.apk > /dev/kmsg
```

Comment: Actually I'm using a hardware emulator so each time it's like trying a fresh version  of OS, so will the above make a difference ? (just asking)

Comment: not in all cases I think. but im working on a project at the moment and when i dont delete the program from my test device before i install it for some reason it wont clear the database stored on the device. so im not sure if it works. but I think its worth giving a try?